# Invalid Block Type "Products are not showing up on home"

Tags: magento-1.9

I am having an invalid block type at the products.info.upsell, and this its not showing the products on hame page.

Undefined variable: block  in /var/www/html/XXXXXX/web/includes/src/__default.php on line 27684

That line is

```
if ($block) {
        $block->setBlockParams($blockParameters);
        foreach ($blockParameters as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($k, $skipParams)) {
                continue;
            }
            $block->setDataUsingMethod($k, $v);
        }
    }
```

How should I repare this error?

The code that I use to appear the products on the home is this one, as said by the theme owner

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id='4' block_name='Óculos Masculinos' template="carousel/products_horizontal.phtml"}}
```

My site is http://grupomari2.dominiotemporario.com/

and should look like this :

http://demo.ethemeuk.com/megatron/magento/demo/index.php?___store=default

Comment: if you change the `block_name` to `name="home.catalog.product"` does that work?

Comment: No, on the template tutorial the block_name could be anything

N - any category id (you can create any inactive category named as carousel name)
block_name - any Title, for example Sale products / Bestsellers / Featured / Top Rated

Comment: Looks like you have compilation ON on your Magento site, I'd recommend turning it OFF while you are correcting the issue.

Comment: I forgot about that, the compilation is turned off now..

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to "allow" the block_type

```
catalog/product_list
```

On **System/Permissions/Blocks**